# Como concatenar o retorno de uma query a uma string de outra mysql

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
 SELECT 
    id   AS CODIGO,
    nome AS NOME,
    versao AS VERSAO,
    build  AS BUILD,
    data   AS DATA
        FROM sistema 
            INTO OUTFILE 'D:/servicos/export/exportaVersao.csv'
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Gostaria de mudar o exporta versão para algum numero aleatório, exemplo:

```
'D:/servicos/export/256589.csv'
```

Eu peguei essa query que gera esse numero:

```
(SELECT FLOOR(10000 + (RAND() * 99999)))
```

Como posso concatenar um com outro ?

Caso não seja possível, ao invés desse numero aleatório poderia ser: `170704 (data = aa/mm/dd)`

Tentativa de concatenar:

```
 SELECT  
    id   AS CODIGO,
    nome AS NOME,
    versao AS VERSAO,
    build  AS BUILD,
    data   AS DATA
        FROM sistema 
            INTO OUTFILE concat(concat('D:/servicos/export/','' ,(SELECT FLOOR(10000 + (RAND() * 99999)))),'.','csv')
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Erro:

> 0 55  01:02:58    SELECT  -- QUERY
>             id   AS CODIGO,
>             nome AS NOME,
>             versao AS VERSAO,
>             build  AS BUILD,
>             data   AS DATA
>              FROM sistema 
>               INTO OUTFILE concat(concat('D:/servicos/export/','' ,(SELECT FLOOR(10000 + (RAND() * 99999)))),'.','csv')
>               FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'concat(concat('D:/servicos/export/',''
>   ,(SELECT FLOOR(10000 + (RAND() * 99999)))' at line 8  0.000 sec

Comment: Já tentou usar a função `concat`?

Comment: Já, mais não deu certo, não sei se é por ser isso: INTO OUTFILE

Comment: Mostre como foi sua tentativa e se teve alguma mensagem de erro

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Adicionei a pergunta.

Comment: eu diria que é parêntese faltando, mas não tenho como ter certeza. Aproveitar também é deixar aqui a [documentação](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/concat/) que indica que com um `concat(str1, str2, str3)` você resolveria o problema, sem precisar de múltiplos. Também note que cálculos podem ser feitos no lugar dos argumentos sem precisar ser uma subconsulta

Comment: Ok, na minha contagem a quantidade de parênteses está correta, então deve ser outra coisa

Comment: Talvez essa string vazia, por que você precisa dela?

Comment: não preciso, vou remover para testar - Testei deu a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
delimiter |
ALTER EVENT ExportaVersao
    ON SCHEDULE 
        EVERY 5 SECOND
    COMMENT 'Exporta Versão do Sistema'
    DO
      BEGIN
      SET @sql_text = 
        CONCAT ("SELECT * FROM SISTEMA  into outfile 'D:/servicos/export/", 
        DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'), 
        ".csv 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'");
       PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
       EXECUTE s1;
       DROP PREPARE s1;
      END|

delimiter ;
```